# keeping only int in python

Tags: python, numbers

so I've run into a situation in which I've opened a .Dat file and tried to extract the numbers from it:

```
self.text= (open("circles.dat", "r")).readlines()
print (self.text)
```

output:

```
['200 200 100\n', '75\t200\t15\n', '   325\t200\t15\n', '\n', '\t200\t\t75 10\n', '200 325 10\n']
```

is there a way I can only extract the int numbers without anything else included.
EDIT:
Eval() cannot be used
I want the output to be something like this:

```
[200,200,100,75,200,15,325,200,15,200,75,10,200,325,10]
```

Comment: You should read line by line and parse each of these lines.

Comment: Do you want a long list of integers, or a list of lists?

Comment: for removing the \t and \n stuff, use eval()

Comment: I want a list of integers and also eval cannot be used

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have all `int`s and just whitespace between them (e.g. space or tab) then you can use a simple list comprehension with `str.split()`:

```
>>> with open("circles.dat", "r") as f:
...     d = [int(a) for l in f for a in l.split()]
>>> d
[200, 200, 100, 75, 200, 15, 325, 200, 15, 200, 75, 10, 200, 325, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> num_list = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', open("circles.dat", "r").read()))
[200, 200, 100, 75, 200, 15, 325, 200, 15, 200, 75, 10, 200, 325, 10]
```

Use `.read()` instead of `.readlines()` as read() returns the content of entire file as a single string (which can be used with regex), unlike readlines() which returns list of string.

After getting the list of numbers (in string form), use `map()` function to typecast the list to `int` type.

**Steps explained**:

```
>>> import re
>>> file_content = open("circles.dat", "r").read()  # Read file as single string
>>> num_list = re.findall(r'\d+', file_content)  # Fetch all numbers from string
>>> num_list
['200', '200', '100', '75', '200', '15', '325', '200', '15', '200', '75', '10', '200', '325', '10']
>>> map(int, num_list)  # Typecast list of str to list of int
[200, 200, 100, 75, 200, 15, 325, 200, 15, 200, 75, 10, 200, 325, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> self.text = (open("circles.dat", "r")).readlines()
>>> print self.text
['200 200 100\n', '75\t200\t15\n', '   325\t200\t15\n', '\n', '\t200\t\t75 10\n', '200 325 10\n']
>>>
>>> ans = map(lambda s: s.rstrip().replace("\t", " "), self.text)
>>> ans = " ".join(ans)
>>> ans = ans.split()
>>>
>>> final_ans = [int(a) for a in ans]
>>> final_ans = map(int, ans)  # alternative
>>> print final_ans
[200, 200, 100, 75, 200, 15, 325, 200, 15, 200, 75, 10, 200, 325, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution without any modules

```
>>> x = ['200 200 100\n', '75\t200\t15\n', '   325\t200\t15\n', '\n', '\t200\t\t75 10\n', '200 325 10\n']
>>> 
>>> y = "".join(x)  # join together
>>> print y
'200 200 100\n75\t200\t15\n   325\t200\t15\n\n\t200\t\t75 10\n200 325 10\n'
>>>
>>> z = y.replace("\t", " ").replace("\n", " ")  # replace tabs and new lines
>>> print z
'200 200 100 75 200 15    325 200 15   200  75 10 200 325 10 '
>>>
>>> z = z.split()  # removes all whitespace by default
>>> print z
['200', '200', '100', '75', '200', '15', '325', '200', '15', '200', '75', '10', '200', '325', '10']
>>> 
>>> res = map(int, z)  # convert all to integers
>>> print res
[200, 200, 100, 75, 200, 15, 325, 200, 15, 200, 75, 10, 200, 325, 10]
```

---

## Solution as an ugly one-liner (at just 80 chars!)

```
res = map(int, "".join(self.text).replace("\t", " ").replace("\n", " ").split())
```